# Creating a DataTable in X++

Tags: datatable, axapta, x++

I'm trying to create a datatable in microsoft ax x++.

I need to return some information back to a webservice.  Problem is i'm having trouble getting this code to work. it runs to the point where i try to add a column because apparently that function doesn't work....

Does anyone have the code in full to create a datatable in x++.  this code works up until the column code.. because basically what i'm doing is query some information and returning it back to a webservice.. unless theres another way to return multiple information back to a webservice that uses c#

```
System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable("MyTable"); 
System.Data.DataColumnCollection columns = dt.get_Columns();
System.Data.DataColumn ProductName;
System.Data.DataColumn QtyOrdered;
System.Data.DataColumn ProductID;
System.Data.DataRow row;

ProductID = new System.Data.DataColumn("ProductID", System.Type::GetType("System.Int32"));
ProductName = new System.Data.DataColumn("ProductName", System.Type::GetType("System.String"));
QtyOrdered = new System.Data.DataColumn("QtyOrdered", System.Type::GetType("System.String"));      
//   dt.Columns.Add(ProductID);
//   dt.Columns.Add(ProductName);
//   dt.Columns.Add(QtyOrdered);    
row=dt.NewRow();
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try replacing lines

```
//    dt.Columns.Add(ProductID);
//    dt.Columns.Add(ProductName);
//    dt.Columns.Add(QtyOrdered);
```

with

```
    columns.Add(ProductID);
    columns.Add(ProductName);
    columns.Add(QtyOrdered);
```

?

**P.S.** To populate the row:

```
    System.Data.DataRowCollection rows = dt.get_Rows();

    ...

    row = dt.NewRow();
    row.set_Item("ProductID", 1);
    row.set_Item("ProductName", "PN");
    row.set_Item("QtyOrdered", "QO");

    rows.Add(row);
```

I suggest you to read some MSDN articles such as [.NET Interop from X++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/cc598160.aspx), [How To Use X++ Syntax for CLR Arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc557456.aspx), etc. - it should help you understand how to use .NET assemblies from X++.

Comment: that works but then how do you populate a row? i tried row[ProductName]="asdf"; and it doesn't work

Comment: ok i got it to work using  row=dt.NewRow();
  row.set_Item(0, "hi");
  row.set_Item(1, "test");

Comment: problem is ... i don't know the code to actually add the row to the data table.. i tried dt.Rows.Add(row); but wasn't working